# Call Azure AD protected Azure Function from console app/PowerShell w/delegated permission

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-functions, adal

What I want to do is have the user log in to the AAD prompt on their Windows Desktop machines, so I get a Bearer token that will work with my Azure Function.

I've followed the tutorial from [this article on adatum](https://adatum.no/azure/azure-ad-authentication-in-azure-functions) but it only covers the application permission (not delegated permissions)

- I already have an Azure Function that is set up for Azure AD
  authentication.
- I already have a client app that I registered (under
  App Registrations).

  - I've configured it to use delegated permissions
    for the Azure Function.

Here's my client code:

```cs
var clientId = "client id for my console app";//console app
var clientUrl = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient");  
var tenant = "tenantid here";
string authority = "https://login.windows.net/" + tenant;

string resource = "https://myaadProtectedFunc.azurewebsites.net";  

AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);

var pp = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto);
var token = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, clientUrl, 
    pp, UserIdentifier.AnyUser).Result;
Console.WriteLine("Got the token: {0}", token.AccessToken);
```

I get an error saying "[my client app] needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it."

Is there some other way to get a Bearer token that will work with my Azure Function?

Answer (score 1):

I did a test and your code does work if you set up the azure side correctly. most likely in the azure function you do not have it set up correctly.

in the azure function did you set up the service principal? 
eg. function app -> platform features -> authentication / authorization -> App Service Authentication to ON -> select azure active directory -> express -> create. -> press ok. -> save.

then in your app registration, you will now see 2. the app reg for your client, and app reg for your function app. in the app reg for your client go to api permissions and add the app registration for your function app with the user impersonation selected.

finally make sure your enterprise application has the user/groups you want to be allowed to access for each of the enterprise apps. (client and function app registration)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I confirmed that I have the proper app registrations and set up the app service authn properly.  I can access my Azure Function fine via the browser, I just want to do this in a console app.

Comment: I tried it via a new console app using c# and .net 4.7.2. and it appeared to work. You mentioned you set up the app registrations and the app service authn. 
Did you apply the proper API Permissions to the app registration too? 
eg Client App Registration -> API Permissions -> Add a permission -> APIs my organization uses -> yourserviceappname -> user_impersonation?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I eventually found another way that does not require registering a separate client application.

Answer (score 1):

Ok it turns out that I don't need to make a separate client application at all.

I can just use the Client ID of the Azure Function.

The thing is that you will have to go to 'Advance' instead of 'Express' because the library `Microsoft.Identity.Client` uses v2.0 tokens.

This is to configure your Azure Function - keep all fields the same, but add a /v2.0 to the Issuer URL:
[image: Choose Advanced]

This is the code to get the delegated bearer token for the Azure Function, which uses the v2.0 token - I don't know how to change it to use the v1 token:

```cs
string[] scopes = new string[] { "profile", "email", "openid" };
string ClientId = [clientId of Azure Function];
string Tenant = [tenantId];
string Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
var _clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
    .WithAuthority($"{Instance}{Tenant}")
    .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
    .Build();
var accounts = _clientApp.GetAccountsAsync().Result;

var authResult = _clientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
            .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
            .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
            .ExecuteAsync().Result;
var bearerTokenForAzureFunction = authResult.IdToken;
```

Now I don't understand the need to register a client application at all if I can get the delegated bearer token this way...